# Javaw.exe cannot be selected in open as default

Tags: windows, default, javaw

I am having the same issue as this person here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691902/java-web-start-cannot-be-selected-as-default-program-on-windows-7

But I am having it with Javaw.exe I simply cannot select as an open with for jar files. I can get it to function on the command line but right clicking on a jar file in explorer does nothing, the previous program stay selected and that Java SE never appears.

I tried this method with java.exe and it worked but javaw.exe simply cannot be selected.

Also note this is win7 64 bit with java 32 installed.

Comment: Try `Shift+Right Click -> Open With -> Browse` then select `javaw.exe`.

Comment: Not sure what the shift is for but that doesn't work either. When I go to the directory that javaw.exe is in and click it to select it it drops back to the choose program screen and nothing changes, it's like I clicked cancel or close and not and application. Never seen anything like this in 20+ years of windows.

Comment: Right now i just wrapped the jar in an exe and that works but I never intended to use that kind of setup. Also unistall and reinstall did not work, manually deleting everything, including registry and ProgramData both Oracle and Sun and then reboot and still no go. Totally confused.